# How to extract the cookie sent by the server with Python requests

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, python-requests, session-cookies

I am trying to get the cookie from a website. If I run the following code:

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
print(session.cookies.get_dict())
response = session.post("http://www.bolsamadrid.es/ing/aspx/Empresas/Empresas.aspx")
print(response.cookies.get_dict())
```

I get nothing (i.e.: {}) The first one should be empty but the second one should include the cookie sent by the website. If I am using web developper tools from either IE or Firefox or Chrome, I get the following cookie: (with some variations - mostly time dependent)

```
__utma  192527929.1793598198.1529696276.1529696276.1529696276.1
__utmb  192527929.2.10.1529696276
__utmc  192527929
__utmt  1
__utmz  192527929.1529696276.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
menuIzq JS
MsjCookies_ing  A;2013/09/23;Fri, 22 Jun 2018 21:37:53 GMT
TopMsj  3
```

What am I doing wrong that requests does not give me that information?